# Riddle - I am a word of 5 letters

Tags: riddle

I am a word of five letters!

People eat me!

If you remove my 1 letter I will be a form of energy!

If you remove my first 2 letters I will be needed for living.

If you remove my first 3 letters I will be a preposition.

If you remove my first 4 letters I will be a drink for you.

Who am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> WHEAT?

If you remove my 1 letter I will be a form of energy!

> HEAT

If you remove my first 2 letters I will be needed for living.

> EAT

If you remove my first 3 letters I will be a preposition.

> AT

If you remove my first 4 letters I will be a drink for you.

> T(EA)